# adding files to firebase storage in vue.js from forms

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, vue.js, firebase-storage

I am trying to add an image to firebase storage using vue.js
my code compiles how I am not obtaining any results 
data is added to firestore I would like to get the download URL as well any suggestions

```
 methods: {
    saveNewAticle() {
      db
        .collection("storys")
        .add({
          title: this.title,
          summary: this.summary,
          article: this.article

        })
        .then(docRef => {
          console.log("Client added: ", docRef.id);
          this.$router.push("/");
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error("Error adding employee: ", error);
        });
       //links ref
       //https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start

      var storageref= storage.ref()
      var thumbnailref  = storageref.child ("images")
      var file = thumbnail  
      var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/${file}').put(file)
      uploadTask
      .on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
       function(snapshot) {

                // /Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
          uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
            console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
          });

      })


    }

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

In function `uploadTask.on(eventName, firstObserver, secondObserver, thirdObserver)`

`firstObserver` is call every time state change

`secondObserver` is error observer which is called on failure

`thirdObserver` is called when uploading completed

To get download url, you need to check in 3rd observer

```
uploadTask
     .on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
      function() {},
      function() {},
      function(snapshot) {

               // /Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
         uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
           console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
         });

     })
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to ittus' answer, be aware that in your `saveNewAticle()` method you are calling two asynchronous operations (the `add()` and the `put()`) without chaining them.

Since you navigate away from the current web page (with `this.$router.push("/");`) **when** the database write is done (i.e. when the promise returned by the `add()` method resolves), you may leave the page **before** the Firebase Storage `put()` method is done.

To avoid this behaviour, you should chain your the promises returned by these two methods. Since you are only interested by knowing when the upload is complete you can use the [`then()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask#then) method as follows (instead of listening for events with [`on()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask#on)):

```
      saveNewAticle() {

        db
        .collection("storys")
        .add({
            title: this.title,
            summary: this.summary,
            article: this.article
        })
        .then(docRef => {

            console.log("Client added: ", docRef.id);

            var storageref = storage.ref()
            var thumbnailref = storageref.child("images")
            var file = thumbnail
            var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/${file}').put(file)

            return uploadTask;

        })
        .then(uploadTaskSnapshot => {

            return uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

        })
        .then(downloadURL => {

            console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
            this.$router.push("/");

        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error adding employee: ", error);
        });

      }
```